# Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio, knitr, pandoc

when I try to knit an R markdown to PDF, I get the following error:

```
Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).
Execution halted
```

However, I have installed pandoc through conda install as well as rstudio through conda.  I also have the right version. This can be seen through the following terminal commands:

```
(base) user@users-MacBook-Pro ~ % which pandoc
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/pandoc

(base) user@Imads-users-Pro ~ % which rstudio
/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/rstudio

(base) imadahmad@Imads-MacBook-Pro ~ % pandoc --version
pandoc 2.12
```

How can I get rstudio to recognize my pandoc installation?

Comment: Could you tell us what version number is reterned when you run `rmarkdown::pandoc_version()` on the console of RStudio, not on the terminal of Mac? If the returned value is different from (or earlier than) Ver. 2.12, then the Pandoc that is bundled with RStudio might be old and you may need to tell rmarkdown to use Pandoc   2.12 by running `rmarkdown::find_pandoc(version = "2.12")`. See also [*Use a Pandoc version not bundled with the RStudio IDE*](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-pandoc.html).